# In TypeScript, how can i get a generic type parameter to be inferred in a method that has multiple type parameters?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript3.0

I'm trying to get the type of `T3` to be inferenced properly in the example below, but it is just being shown as `unknown`. I can't understand how it can properly infer the base type `T2` when calling `Testing.testIt`, but not the type parameter for the class it extends (`T3`). Here is the [running example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-testing-type-inference). I was trying to figure out if the `infer` keyword would be useful here, but I can't see how that would fit into this.

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

class GenericClass<T> {
}

class ChildClass extends GenericClass<string> {

}

class Testing {
    static testIt<T3, T2 extends GenericClass<T3>>(testClass: Type<T2>): T3 {
      console.log('testIt called');
      return '' as any;
    }

    static testIt2(val: string): void {
      console.log(val);
    }
}

const result = Testing.testIt(ChildClass);
Testing.testIt2(result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to define a helper to extract the type:

```
type ExtractGenericClassType<T> = T extends GenericClass<infer TInner> ? TInner : never;

class Testing {
    static testIt<T extends GenericClass<any>>(testClass: Type<T>): ExtractGenericClassType<T> {
      ...
    }
}
```

Moreover, you need to ensure that your generic class actually uses the generic type parameter, otherwise this will not work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had tried something very similar, but I just wasn't sure what to put for the type parameter inside of `GenericClass`. Looking at it now though, I guess `any` makes sense, but it still seems a little weird to me.

Comment: "ensure that your generic class actually uses the generic type parameter"  relevant [FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I was wondering if that was in their documentation anywhere, I just didn't know what to search for to find it.